# Sending an email with attachment displays in encoded format PHP

Tags: php, email

This is the  code am using to send an email with a doc file attached to it,
am receiving the email but the content in the email is displaying in a encoded text format

```
<?php

$to = $_POST['to'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$fileatt = $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'];
$fileatt_type = $_FILES['upload_file']['type'];//application/msword
$fileatt_name = $_FILES['upload_file']['name'];

$headers = "From: $from";

if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {

$file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);


$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";


$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$message . "\n\n";


$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));


$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
}

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

**email am receiving is like this**

```
message:This is a multi-part message in MIME format. --==Multipart_Boundary_x788f8ac40875c8c7a6540be6654be9c8x Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit --==Multipart_Boundary_x788f8ac40875c8c7a6540be6654be9c8x Content-Type: application/msword; name="File_name.doc" Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="File_name.doc" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 s pcEAW4AJBAAA+BK/AAAAAAAAEAAAAAAACAAAMhMAAA4AYmpiaqz6rPoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAJBBYAuEAAAM6QAQDOkAEAFwsAAAAAAAAaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD//w8AAAAA AAAAAAD//w8AAAAAAAAAAAD//w8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALcAAAAAAEgHAAAAAAAASAcAAIsU AAAAAAAAixQAAAAAAACLFAAAAAAAAIsUAAAAAAAAixQAADQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP////8AAAAAvxQA AAAAAAC/FAAAAAAAAL8UAABoAAAAJxUAAEwAAABzFQAAbAAAAL8UAAAAAAAAj0UAAMYCAADfFQAA FgAAAPUVAAAQAAAABRYAAAAAAAAFFgAAAAAAAAUWAAAAAAAAJBcAACYAAABKFwAADAAAAFYXAAAI AAAADkUAAAIAAAAQRQAAAAAAABBFAAAAAAAAEEUAAAAAAAAQRQAAAAAAABBFAAAAAAAAEEUAACQA AABVSAAAogIAAPdKAAA8AAAANEUAABUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAixQAAAAAAABeFwAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAkFwAAAAAAACQXAAAAAAAAXhcAAAAAAABeFwAAAAAAADRFAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAACLFAAAAAAAAIsUAAAAAAAABRYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUWAAAfAQAASUUAABYAAADc GgAAAAAAANwaAAAAAAAA3BoAAAAAAABeFwAADAEAAIsUAAAAAAAABRYAAAAAAACLFAAAAAAAAAUW AAAAAAAADkUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANwaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAXhcAAAAAAAAORQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA3BoAAAAAAADcGgAA pgEAAJY+AAAwAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKkIAAAAAAAAFFgAAAAAAAP////8AAAAA0NGIQpry zAEAAAAAAAAAAL8UAAAAAAAAahgAACIAAADGPwAAJAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+kQAABQAAABfRQAAMAAA AI9FAAAAAAAA6j8AAEACAAAzSwAAAAAAAIwYAABQAgAAM0sAAEgAAAAqQgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAADNLAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACLFAAAAAAAACpCAADQAgAAXhcAAAAAAABeFwAAAAAAANwa AAAAAAAAXhcAAAAAAABeFwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAXhcA AAAAAABeFwAAAAAAAF4XAAAAAAAANEUAAAAAAAA0RQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA== --==Multipart_Boundary_x788f8ac40875c8c7a6540be6654be9c8x--

headers:From:  MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x788f8ac40875c8c7a6540be6654be9c8x"
```

So can anyone help me with a perfect code
Thank u in advance

Comment: what about using charset = utf-8 ?

Comment: @Deepanshu no it dnt work

Comment: and what about "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";  ?
actually i dont know what 7 bit does, just give it a try

Comment: @Deepanshu dat dnt wrk

Comment: Take a look at http://fil.ya1.ru/PHP_5_in_Practice/index.htm#page=0768667437/ch16lev1sec1.html

Answer (score 0):

Find out the reason yourself by really debugging the issue at hand instead of *guessing*:

1. Dump the messages content you generate into a text file.
2. Dump any valid messages content you received in an email client into a file (the messages SOURCE code).
3. Compare both files and take your answer from the difference.

That works, really.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't support default utf-8 encoding, you need to pass the relevant encoding function as given in the following to your headers

```
Replace your code 

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n

to

"Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: The normal problem with the encoding will be with respect to utf -8 characters....However i tried using your code and was able to receive mail with the attachment properly....i echoed the $message content and can see the base64 encoded info on the browser

Comment: If your message body is related to "$_POST['message']", then it is working absolutely fine.